# How do I use mod_rewrite to use old parameters in new URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a domain that I am creating requests for in this format:
https://example.com/dir1/uniqueID/dir2

Note: This unique ID will have 6 random characters of A-Z or 0-9.

I want to redirect users to: https://example.com:another_port/?var_name=uniqueID

Everything I've been seeing has revolved around that var_name=uniqueID was in the original URL (e.g. https://example.com/dir1/var_name=uniqueID/dir2), but if that uniqueID is a separate parameter without being assigned to a value (as I have), then documentation appears to be non-existent.

This has been the start of the RewriteRule that I have created, but it's clearly not finished. It could be wrong also, which is why I'm asking for help.

> RewriteRule /dir1/(.*)/dir2/  https://example.com:another_port/?var_name=uniqueID [L]

Answer (score 0):

To take a piece of a regex match and insert it into the replacement you use `$n` where `n` is the `n`th matched string, e.g., `$1` to insert the first match:

```
RewriteRule "/dir1/(.*)/dir2/" "https://example.com:another_port/?var_name=$1" [L]
```

Although I'm guessing you want `/dir1` to be at the start of the pathname (you don't want to match `/foo/dir1/foo/dir2/`) and you don't want that middle part to include slashes (you don't want to match `/dir1/foo/bar/dir2/`) so you more likely want this:

```
RewriteRule "^/dir1/([^/]*)/dir2/" "https://example.com:another_port/?var_name=$1" [L]
```

The `^` at the beginning means "the beginning of the string" and the `[^/]` means "match anything that's not a slash"

Oh, and I'm also assuming you don't care about anything following `/dir2/` (e.g., `/dir1/foo/dir2/foo.html`)

If you only want to match paths ending in `/dir2/` then just throw a `$` at the end (`$` matches the end of a string) like this:

```
RewriteRule "^/dir1/([^/]*)/dir2/$" "https://example.com:another_port/?var_name=$1" [L]
```

If you wanted to capture whatever comes after and embed it in the destination URL, then you'd put in another capture group (e.g., `…/dir2/(.*)`) and use `$2` in the destination URL to insert the captured text wherever you want it.)

I'd recommend finding and reading a tutorial for regular expression syntax.